# c: ignores return and function is repeated

Tags: c, function, return

I have to determine if a graph is connected or not.

I think that I used bad the concept of return here, but the problem is: when top =<0 and k == vertecsfuncion, enters the penultimate if, and what I wanted with return 0; is to ending function and carrying on with the execution. But when it arrives to return 0; it go up another time to while(top>0). This happens two times, while the second time, top increases one (I don't know how) and then arrives the "error".
Thank you for your time.

```
int connex(int **matrix, int *visited, Pila *p, int vertucsfuncion, int k,int x, int top){

    int u,j,c,f,contdos=0, cont=0;      
    x = PILA_top(*p);

    printf("\n%d\n",top);

    while (top > 0){

        cont = 0;           
        k++;

        for(u=0;u<k;u++){
            if(visited[u]!=x){
                contdos++;
            }
        }

        if (contdos==k){
            visited[contdos-1]=x;
            contdos = 0;
        }else{
            k--;
            contdos = 0;
        }       

        for(j=0;j<vertucsfuncion;j++){
            if(matrix[(x-1)][j]!=0){
                if(j!=(x-1)){
                    matrix[(x-1)][j]=matrix[(x-1)][j]-1;
                    matrix[j][(x-1)]=matrix[j][(x-1)]-1;
                    for(c=0;c<vertucsfuncion;c++){
                        for(f=0;f<vertucsfuncion;f++){
                            printf("|%d|",matrix[c][f]);
                        }
                        printf("\n");
                    }
                    printf("\n");
                    PILA_push(p,(j+1));
                    top++;
                    x = PILA_top(*p);
                    connex(matrix,visited,p,vertucsfuncion,k,x,top);
                }else{
                    matrix[(x-1)][j]=matrix[(x-1)][j]-1;
                    for(c=0;c<vertucsfuncion;c++){
                        for(f=0;f<vertucsfuncion;f++){
                            printf("|%d|",matrix[c][f]);
                        }
                        printf("\n");
                    }
                    PILA_push(p,(j+1));
                    top++;

                    connex(matrix,visited,p,vertucsfuncion,k,x,top);
                }               
            }               
            cont++;             
        }

        if(cont == vertucsfuncion ){                
            PILA_pop(p);
            top--;
            connex(matrix,visited,p,vertucsfuncion,k,x,top);
        }   
    }
    if(k==vertucsfuncion){
        printf("Is connex");
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Didn't understand your question.

Comment: So, I don't know, when I arrive to return 0; the function contuinue. And what I want is to funish the function when arriving to return 0;

Comment: Strong text is added by "stack overflow".

Comment: @moffeltje yes I know it, but when top=0; it ignores the return 0; and (I don't know how) icreases one the variable top...

Comment: I have done it but it is so strange. After printing two times "is connex", top increases 1 and by the time of the first printf "is connex", the function should have "stopped". Do you see any problem with returns? @moffeltje

Answer (score 1):

Inside connex, inside the `while(top>0)` loop you are recursively calling connex again:

```
top--;
connex(matrix,visited,p,vertucsfuncion,k,x,top);
```

When this second call to connex calls `return 0` it will only return from the inner call to connex and the outer call will still proceed with the `while(top >0)` loop.

Comment: Yes, I'm calling connex recurvively, but, can you explain me what you say? I did not understand it.. I'm sorry of my level of programming.

Comment: @user3129585 If you have a function that calls itself again, then there are two instances of the same function. Each instance of the function has it's own variable set. You can see that if you run the program in a debugger and step through it.

Comment: @user3129585 Before implementing such a complex function like connex you should first learn about recursive programming. You should also check if recursion really is necessary in your case.

Comment: But at the time of "return 0", the function might stop, or no? Even is connex or not.

Comment: @user3129585 At the time of `return 0` the current instance of connex is returning/stopping and the function that called that instance of connex gains control again. If the calling function was connex itself, then the previous instance of connex is proceeding with its work.